# Fading a View in a ListView item - with a twist

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, fade

I'm trying to find some kind of elegant solution for fading in/out a TextView that is part of an item in a ListView.

To give you some context, the listview shows a list of players in a basketball game. The user taps on a name and is provided with a dialog to log an event, for example a shot or a foul for that player. Once the dialog is dismissed the user is brought back to the listview and it is here that I'd like to provide some feedback about the event that has just been logged.

The way I'd like to do it is to have a small string appear for about 5 seconds in the view of the item (player) that has just been tapped on. The small string would display something like "3rd foul" or "4 turnovers".

A naive implementation is straightforward. Change the text of the view to the required string and then start an animation that fades in the view, keeps it there for a while and then fades it out. Problems arise however when a second event for the same player is logged shortly after the first. Ideally the first feedback string should be allowed to stay for the allotted 5 seconds and the second string should fade in/out in the next 5 seconds.

This queueing of animation and text changes on a per-player bases I'm not quite sure how to implement. Furthermore, I'm concerned by the interaction between the animations and the Activity's life cycle. What happens (or should happen) to the queued animations when the activity is sent to the background, stopped or even removed from memory? Or when an item is removed from the ArrayAdapter behind the listview?

Thoughts?

Manu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about the lifecycle of the activity. There will be no adverse effects. However if the activity goes into the background during the animation, the animation will take place and you will not see it.

As for haveing one animation wait for the next, simply do this:

```
// here we will keep track of any listView and when the last animation took place.
// The keys will be your listView identifiers. Here I assumed an integer, but use whatever is a good ID for your listView
private HashMap<Integer, Long> listViewLastAnimations;

// the length of the animation in milliseconds
private static long ANIMATION_LENGTH_MS = 5000;

// put this code where  you would start your animation
// get when the last event animation occurred
Long lastAnimation = listViewLastAnimations.get(YOUR_LIST_ITEM_IDENTIFIER);
Date new = new Date();
if (lastAnimation == null ||
   new.currentTimeMillis () - lastAnimation > ANIMATION_LENGTH_MS ){
listViewLastAnimations.put(YOUR_LIST_ITEM_IDENTIFIER, new.currentTimeMillis ());
// perform animation as normal
}else{
// set a delay to your animation with
long delay = ANIMATION_LENGTH_MS - (new.currentTimeMillis () - lastAnimation);
listViewLastAnimations.put(YOUR_LIST_ITEM_IDENTIFIER, new.currentTimeMillis () + delay);
setStartOffset(delay) ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kyle for your answer! I like its simplicity! I will be implementing in the next few days hopefully. I'll let you know!